# Installing and injecting ng-flow using yeoman

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, meanjs

I am working with the yo meanjs boilerplate from  here  :[yo meanjs](http://meanjs.org/).

I know I can create my own module using `$ yo meanjs:angular-module <module-name>` .

Is it possible to install and inject into my controller [ng-flow](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow)  using yo from the command line?

Something like : `$ yo meanjs:ng-flow <module-name>`

In the documentation it states  found here [meanjs modules](http://meanjs.org/docs.html#angularjs-modules): So unless there are any better suggestions I might try this route.

**To add third-party modules use the public/config.js file where we added an array property called applicationModuleVendorDependencies. When you add a new third-party module you should add it to this array so the main module can load it as a depenedency.**

```
'use strict';

// Init the application configuration module for AngularJS application

var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
    // Init module configuration options
    var applicationModuleName = 'theconnect';
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils'];

        // Add a new vertical module
        var registerModule = function(moduleName, dependencies) {
            // Create angular module
            angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);

            // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
            angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
        };

        return {
            applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
            applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
            registerModule: registerModule
        };
    })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding module via cmd line using :

```
bower install "ng-flow#~2" --save
 grunt bower-install
```

I added it as as dependency to public/config.js :

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils','flow'];
```

then added the module path to the all the JS files  under the `/config/env` directory.

```
module.exports = {
    db: process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost') + '/theconnect',
    assets: {
        lib: {
            css: [
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',
            ],
            js: [
                'public/lib/angular/angular.min.js',
                'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
                'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
                'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.min.js',
                'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
                'public/lib/ng-flow/dist/ng-flow.js'
            ]
        },
        css: 'public/dist/application.min.css',
        js: 'public/dist/application.min.js'
    },
......
...
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed after installing flow into meanjs. Thanks Fabii. Tiny clarification....  the module path file to update is /config/env/all.js.

Answer (score 0):

Fabii's answer is helpful.  To add to it...

I had to make 2 entries in the "all.js" file Fabii mentioned (which is located at /config/env/all.js

```
'public/lib/flow.js/dist/flow.min.js',
'public/lib/ng-flow/dist/ng-flow.js'
```