# Module 'flow' not available in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flow-js

in my app.js I have included the dependency for flow

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router', 'ngResource', 'flow']);
```

I have included the javascript in my index file to load as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/flow.js/2.0.0b2/flow.js"></script>
```

I am getting the error Module 'flow' is not available!

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module flow due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'flow' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=flow
```

Comment: did u add the `flow.js` below to the `angular.js` and top to the `app.js`

Comment: also u need to add `angular flow` `https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/blob/master/dist/ng-flow.js`

Comment: that seems to work, now I have both. can you explain what is the difference ?

Comment: `flow.js` can use with `jquery` but when u use `angularjs` there is angularjs version of flow.js called `ng-flow.js` in `ng-flow` u can have the `angular modules` but in plain `flow.js` u dont have modules

Comment: and u dont need the plain `flow.js`. remove it. `ng-flow.js` should  be enough

Comment: I am using this <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/anglular.flow/2.2.0/ng-flow-standalone.js"></script>..is that the right one ?

Comment: can you please share some examples .. I am not sure how to call flow in my controller. I googled , but examples are hard to find. appreciate your help.

Comment: For a detailed solution when using MeanJS, see [Installing and injecting ng-flow using yeoman][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394686/installing-and-injecting-ng-flow-using-yeoman

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because if you want to use the ['flow'] module in angularJs you have to include both:flow.js and ng-flow.
If you are using bower and it is configured to place the libraries on the js/vendor you would have to do something like this.

```
bower install "ng-flow#~2" --save


{{ HTML::script('js/vendor/flow.js/dist/flow.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/vendor/ng-flow/dist/ng-flow.min.js') }}
```

If you are not, just look for a ng-flow CDN.

Best regards!

Comment: This is the problem I ran into. I used bower to install it and missed the "ng-flow" directory.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include http: before your cdn:

change your script to this and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/flow.js/2.0.0b2/flow.js"></script>
```

Comment: No it does matter. Try to check in development tools for resources that are getting loaded and you will see that the cdn failed to load.

Comment: Why exactly should "http:" be included? You don't provide any explanation.

Comment: URL's without a protocol are assumed to be in the same domain as the page. So `cdn.jsdelivr.net` is just part of the path.

Comment: including http is very assumptions that the application will not be run under ssl. The simple '//path' will work just fine. SSL or not.